# jqgrid error message

Tags: jqgrid-php

When I click on "add", a form is opened. Suppose there are few "required" fields on that form and I leave them all empty. Now when I press "submit" button on form, only error about the first "required" field is shown, not for all the required fields. When I rectify first required field and press submit again, only then it tells about second required field. I want to show all errors about required fields once and together. I hope that clarifies the question.